# Unzip executable files for all plataforms

Tags: cross-platform, unzip, platform

I need to download the executable unzip files for all platforms possible.

```
    echo "1 = windows_intelx86 (Microsoft Windows (98 or later) running on an Intel x86-compatible CPU)"
    echo "2 = windows_x86_64 (Microsoft Windows running on an AMD x86_64 or Intel EM64T CPU)"
    echo "3 = i686-pc-linux-gnu (Linux running on an Intel x86-compatible CPU)"
    echo "4 = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Linux running on an AMD x86_64 or Intel EM64T CPU)"
    echo "5 = powerpc-linux-gnu (Linux running on a 32-bit PowerPC processor)"
    echo "6 = ppc64-linux-gnu (Linux running on a 64-bit PowerPC processor)"
    echo "7 = alpha-hp-linux-gnu (Linux running on Alpha)"
    echo "8 = ia64-linux-gnu (Linux running on IA64 (Itanium))"
    echo "9 = sparc-sun-linux-gnu (Linux running on SPARC)"
    echo "10= sparc64-sun-linux-gnu (Linux running on SPARC 64-bit)"
    echo "11= powerpc-apple-darwin (Mac OS X 10.3 or later running on Motorola PowerPC)"
    echo "12= i686-apple-darwin (Mac OS 10.4+ running on an Intel CPU)"
    echo "13= x86_64-apple-darwin (Mac OS 10.5+ running on an Intel 64-bit CPU)"
    echo "14= sparc-sun-solaris2.7 (Solaris 2.7 running on a SPARC-compatible CPU)"
    echo "15= sparc-sun-solaris (Solaris 2.8+ running on a SPARC-compatible CPU)"
    echo "16= sparc64-sun-solaris (Solaris 2.8+ running on a SPARC 64-bit CPU)"
    echo "17= hppa-hp-hpux (HPUX running on 32-bit HPPA)"
    echo "18= hppa64-hp-hpux (HPUX running on 64-bit HPPA)"
    echo "19= alpha-hp-tru64 (Tru64 Unix running on Alpha)"
    echo "20= ia64-hp-hpux (HPUX running on IA64)"
    echo "21= powerpc-ibm-aix (AIX running on PowerPC)"
    echo "22= i686-pc-freebsd (FreeBSD on x86)"
    echo "23= x86_64-pc-freebsd (FreeBSD on Intel-compatible 64-bit)"
    echo "24= i686-pc-openbsd (OpenBSD on x86)"
    echo "25= x86_64-pc-openbsd (OpenBSD on Intel-compatible 64-bit)"
    echo "26= i686-pc-solaris (Solaris 2.8+ on an Intel x86-compatible CPU)"
    echo "27= x86_64-pc-solaris (Solaris 2.8+ on an AMD x86_64 or Intel EM64T CPU)"
    echo "28= i586-pc-haiku (Haiku on an Intel x86-compatible CPU)"
    echo "29= powerpc64-ps3-linux-gnu (Sony Playstation 3 (Cell processor) running Linux)"
    echo "30= arm-android-linux-gnu (Android running on ARM)"
```

I found this web site, but there is not the executable files that I need.
http://www.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/UnZip.html#Downloads

Does anyone know where I can find these files to download?

Thanks
Felipe

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't use [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) or something similar in your program to decompress files programatically?

Comment: I downloaded the http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/libpng/zlib-1.2.7.tar.gz?download but it has the same files like unzip. Make files. With these I need to install at least a virtual machine on my computer. I would like to download a executable unzip to descompress a file using just one command line. Thanks.